# Quote Item level manual Discount - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, quote, discount, quoteitem

I need to give Quote Item level manual Discount for selected cart items. After giving discount Cart Item row total will change. As can't modify the product price so custom price solution is also not working.

I tried with a new discount total but it gives a discount on the whole cart.

Anyone, please suggest the best approach for giving a discount on Cart item level without modifying product price.

Comment: hello @Panakj, got solution for it?

Comment: Facing same issue to give discount to individual item any idea ?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/365333/magento-2-add-discount-based-on-individual-qty-and-item-to-cart

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin for Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator::process -

```
    class Myplugin
       {

        protected $discountFactory;

        public function __construct(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\DataFactory $discountFactory){
        $this->discountFactory = $discountFactory;
    }

    public function aroundProcess(
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $item,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator $validator
    ){
        $returnValue = $proceed($item);

        $discountData = $this->discountFactory->create();

        $discountData->setAmount('[my_discount_amount]');
        $discountData->setBaseAmount('[my_discount_amount]');
        $discountData->setOriginalAmount('[my_discount_amount]');
        $discountData->setBaseOriginalAmount('[my_discount_amount]');

        $this->setDiscountData($discountData, $item);

        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

Replace the [my_discount_amount] with your discount amount.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting Call to undefined method setDiscountData error. Any idea ?

Comment: hello, @NoamN pls update full code, also this code sets the mannual discount on each quote item?

Comment: Hi, you should add cart rule condition in marketting -> cart price rules -> rule name -> "actions" tab rule configuration. There it will apply on cart item level instead of entire cart. Thanks.

Comment: Facing same issue to give discount to individual item any idea ?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/365333/magento-2-add-discount-based-on-individual-qty-and-item-to-cart